# I want to visit South Africa from the US

Tags: visas

I want to vist South Africa. I have a passport. I want to know if I will need a visa to go for 2 weeks on vacation from the US.

Comment: To be clear, are you a US citizen with a US passport, or is your passport from some other country?

Answer (score 2):

The official South African consulate in New York says [US citizens do not need a visa](https://www.southafrica-newyork.net/homeaffairs/visitorsvisa.htm) for a visit of up to 90 days.

> U.S. citizens (U.S. passport holders) visiting the Republic of South Africa for ninety (90) days or less for tourism / business purposes do not need visas.

In addition, your passport must be valid until at least 30 days after your intended date of departure from South Africa.

> Foreigners who wish to visit South Africa must have passports / travel documents valid for thirty (30) more days after the intended return date from South Africa.

Just make sure your passport has enough time left before its expiration, (renew it if it doesn't) book your tickets and go.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean "want" and not "won't"(which is the exact opposite": as a US citizen you don't need a visa

> U.S. citizens (U.S. passport holders) visiting the Republic of South
>   Africa for ninety (90) days or less for tourism / business purposes do
>   not need visas.

Source: https://www.southafrica-newyork.net/homeaffairs/visitorsvisa.htm

Comment: It's not necessary to repeat answers which have already been posted.

Comment: @MichaelHampton with the 'want' and 'won't' it is a good answer that stands, adding the same information again does not hurt as it makes for a real answer.

Comment: @Willeke Don't we normally try to fix posts which use poor English?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I would normally, but in this case the change is quite big. (I will not roll back your edit but I would not have edited to something the opposite from what was posted.

Comment: @Willeke I'm quite confident in it, as I know American English and this particular error is quite common (unfortunately) in the US.

Comment: Sorry, I posted this when no other answer was up yet.